# IBM Worklight 6.2 - upgrade from 6.0 NullPointerException

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I am upgrading an existing Worklight v.6.0 project to the new 6.2. I get this error:

```
[2014-06-20 10:39:08] FWLST1022I: Starting to migrate the XXXX project from    version 6.0.0 to version 6.2.0.00.20140613-0730. 
[2014-06-20 10:39:08] FWLPL0025I: The XXXX project is being saved as   C:\Users\XXXX_2014_06_20_103908.backup.zip file. 
[2014-06-20 10:39:14]             C:\Users\XXXX\android\native\AndroidManifest.xml changed android:minSdkVersion to:9 
[2014-06-20 10:39:14]             C:\Users\XXXX\android\native\AndroidManifest.xml changed android:minSdkVersion to:9 
[2014-06-20 10:39:14]             Unexpected error during upgrade: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.worklight.upgrader.upgraders.android.AppAndroidCordova31ConfigXMLUpgrader.getVersion(AppAndroidCordova31ConfigXMLUpgrader.java:255) 
at com.worklight.upgrader.upgraders.android.AppAndroidCordova31ConfigXMLUpgrader.upgrade(AppAn droidCordova31ConfigXMLUpgrader.java:89) 
at com.worklight.upgrader.WLUpgradeEngine.executeUpgrader(WLUpgradeEngine.java:311) at com.worklight.upgrader.WLUpgradeEngine.performUpgrade(WLUpgradeEngine.java:280) 
at com.worklight.upgrader.WLUpgradeEngine.upgradeProject(WLUpgradeEngine.java:183) at com.worklight.studio.plugin.upgrader.WLUpgraderWorkspaceJob.runInWorkspace(WLUpgraderWorkspaceJob.java:132) 
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Any hint?

Comment: Well, it looks like an upgrade path bug. Can you provide a demo project so that we could reproduce it?

Comment: One thing you can try... if you do not have any custom native code in the android\native folder, try deleting the native folder and then importing the 6.0.0.x project to 6.2.0.0 and see if it passes.

Comment: If you do have custom native code, you can mirror the file structure of the native folder in the nativeResources folder just below it. This way - after the upgrade, and during build time - your custom code will be auto-copied from the nativeResoures folder to the native folder.

Comment: Yes! I removed all native folders (Android, iPhone), then rebuilt them from scratch and it worked. It just complained that "Requested to build 'android' but there is no optimization folder for it.", but then it worked. Thank you!

Comment: good to hear. I've written the above as an answer. Please accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you provide a demo project (yours if possible) that reproduces this issue? We'd like to take a look.

As a workaround: if you do not have any custom native code in the android\native folder, delete the native folder and then import the 6.0.0.x project to 6.2.0.0. Should work.

For anyone who might have custom code: you can mirror the file structure of the native folder in the nativeResources folder just below it. This way - after the upgrade, and during build time - the custom code will be auto-copied from the nativeResoucres folder to the native folder.